# How can I expand records n-number of times and calculate Datediff for dates in same field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to expand a table n-number of times, based on frequency counts of records, and find Datediff between quarter-end dates, or month-end dates, based on 'mxMonth'.  Please see all details below and let me know if clarification is needed...I understand this is complicated...

```
-----DLL

CREATE TABLE Reporting_Table (
    Credit_Line_NO    Varchar(10),
    noMonths         INT,
    EFFECTIVEDATE    Date,
    EXPIRY_DATE      Date,
    Amount           Money,
    mxDays           INT,
    mxFactor         decimal(5,4),
    Calc             Money)

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc)
 Values('9938810','3','3/31/2018','6/12/2020','11718.75','90','1','11718.75') 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc)
 Values('2235461','1','6/30/2018','6/6/2019','12345','30','1','12345') 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc)
 Values('3365434','12','6/30/2018','6/30/2019','298523.36085','365','1.01388888888889','302669.518639583') 


 Select *, (DATEDIFF(MONTH,EFFECTIVEDATE,EXPIRY_DATE)/noMonths)+1 as FREQ
 From Reporting_Table
```

[image]

This will give me FREQ, and I want to expand each row by the FREQ number; so I want to copy Credit_Line_NO 10 times, 2235461 13 times, and 3365434 1 times ()if noMonths=12 then FREQ=1.

Next, based on noMonths, I know there are 10 periods (quarterly periods because noMonths = 3) between EFFECTIVEDATE and EXPIRY_DATE.  Here are the 10 quarter-end periods.
I want to calculate the number of days between each Quarter_End_Date (and between monthly-end date if the frequency is monthly), as such.

[image]

The first quarter end date will have 90 days.  Each subsequent calculation is based on the number of days in the quarter.  Finally, the last period is always less than the full quarter (or less than 1 month if the period is monthly), so I want to calculate the actual days between

I have the following cte which does some very useful things for me.  I just want to modify it to do the following:

```
#1) insert number of rows equal to the FREQ
#2) get quarter-end dates (or month-end dates of frequency is monthly)
#3) get number of days between dates
```

--CTE

```
with cte as (
    select 
        *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Credit_Line_NO order by REVIEW_FREQUENCY)
        from 
        TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST
)
select
    *,
    SUBSTRING(REVIEW_FREQUENCY,10,2) as mxMonth,
    RIGHT(REVIEW_FREQUENCY,2) as mxDays,
    CAST(LEFT(REVIEW_FREQUENCY,8) as DATE) as mxStartDate,
    CAST(EXPIRY_DATE AS DATE) as mxEndDate,
    FREQ = CASE  WHEN SUBSTRING(REVIEW_FREQUENCY,10,2) = 01 THEN 30
                 WHEN SUBSTRING(REVIEW_FREQUENCY,10,2) = 03 THEN 90
                 WHEN SUBSTRING(REVIEW_FREQUENCY,10,2) = 12 THEN 365
           END,
    CAST(round((DATEDIFF(MONTH,cast(LEFT(REVIEW_FREQUENCY,8) as DATE),CAST(EXPIRY_DATE AS DATE)))/cast(LEFT(SUBSTRING(REVIEW_FREQUENCY, CHARINDEX('M',review_frequency)+1,LEN(REVIEW_FREQUENCY)),2) as decimal)+0.4,0) AS INTEGER) AS FREQUENCY
from
    cte a
WHERE REVIEW_FREQUENCY NOT LIKE '%DAILY%'
ORDER BY Credit_Line_NO, rn
```

I think this requires a bit more logic; something like this:

```
FROM cte a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(FREQUENCY)+1,0) FROM cte) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY REVIEW_FREQUENCY))
WHERE B.RN < = A.FREQUENCY
```

Of course that throws an error.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Seems to me like #2 and #3 would be pretty easy for you if you had the rows. The best way to generate rows like this is to use a tally table. You simply join to it where its value is <= Freq. Here is a great explanation of a tally table. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: Like @SeanLange said, a tally table could do the trick, but you could also make use of a [tag:recursive-cte].

Comment: Yes, either option would probably work.  What would it actually look like?  Can someone post some code?  I tested a few ideas, including what I described above, but so far I haven't been able to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just worked out a solution to this issue.  The following script works as intended.

```
;with cte as
(
  select Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc,
         (DATEDIFF(MONTH,EFFECTIVEDATE,EXPIRY_DATE)/noMonths)+1 as FREQ,
         1 as Rec_Iteration
  from Reporting_Table
  where noMonths > 1
  union all  
  select Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc,
         (DATEDIFF(MONTH,EFFECTIVEDATE,EXPIRY_DATE)/noMonths)+1 as FREQ,
         Rec_Iteration + 1
  from cte 
  where Rec_Iteration < FREQ
)
select Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc,
    (DATEDIFF(MONTH,EFFECTIVEDATE,EXPIRY_DATE)/noMonths)+1 as FREQ
from cte
order by Credit_Line_NO,
         Rec_Iteration
```

Comment: This looks like it would work but be careful here. Using a recursive cte like is pretty much the same thing as a loop. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/ If you have a large dataset this is going to perform pretty badly. A tally table will scale much better here.

Comment: Yes, yes, it makes sense.  For now, I just want to make it work.  In the near future I can take some time to figure out how to optimize it.  I did some research on the Tally Table, but I'm still not sure how it would work, other than maybe list numbers 1-22497, which is how many rows I need to expand to.

Comment: You use a tally table by joining to it, typically with a <= so you get multiple rows returned. It is your code and your system but I would caution you against the mentality of "good enough for now". That is a very common trap in the programming world. You will never come back and fix it later and the performance problem will always be there. This is what happens when you need stuff done "right now" instead of done "right".